# MySQL - change OR to AND

Tags: mysql, sql

Let's presume I have the following query:

```
SELECT Ads.AdId 
  FROM Ads
     , AdsAmenities 
 WHERE AdsAmenities.amenities_AmenityId IN (2, 18, 1) 
   AND Ads.AdId = AdsAmenities.ads_AdId
```

This query selects each AdId from the Ads table, which has **at least one** of the following three amenities (2, 18, 1). The `AdsAmenities` table is the one, where I store the relation between `Ads` and `Amenities`. How could I change this query, that it should return only the AdId's which have **all of the enumerated amenity ids**?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try with `having`:

```
SELECT Ads.AdId 
FROM Ads 
JOIN AdsAmenities ON Ads.AdId = AdsAmenities.ads_AdId 
WHERE AdsAmenities.amenities_AmenityId IN (2, 18, 1) 
GROUP BY Ads.AdId
HAVING COUNT(distinct AdsAmenities.amenities_AmenityId) = 3
```

In case `AdsAmenities.amenities_AmenityId` values are uniq, you can skip the `distinct` part.

Comment: could you explain what's the difference between your answer, and the answer below yours? I mean, it works both ways as I see, and I am interested that using the JOIN you provided has any advantages at all then? I mark this as the correct answer, because you were faster:)

Comment: @AdamBaranyai: 1) I am using explicit `join` notation instead on implicit (that you've provided), which is deprecated (the implicit one). 2) Our answers aren't identical in case `AdsAmenities.amenities_AmenityId` in the result set is not uniq, i.e.  in case there are three rows like (2,2,18) for one `AdsAmenities.amenities_AmenityId`, the query below returns corresponding `Ads.AdId`, while my query doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you need a `HAVING COUNT(...)` clause here:

```
SELECT Ads.AdId FROM Ads, AdsAmenities 
   WHERE AdsAmenities.amenities_AmenityId IN (2, 18, 1) AND Ads.AdId = AdsAmenities.ads_AdId 
   GROUP BY Ads.AdId
HAVING COUNT(AdsAmenities.amenities_AmenityId) >= 3
```